# Listen for variable and trigger rebuild in Flutter GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

I am using Flutter **GetX** and would like to listen to some variables in my custom GetXController...

```
class HomeScreenController extends MyGetXController {
    var isLoading = false.obs;
    var isError = true.obs;
}
```

**The Problem**:

I want to use the observed variables in my Scaffold...and whenever it changes it should trigger rebuild of widget...But the only way I found is putting them into an `ObX() Widget`. But I want to listen to the observed variables without having to use `ObX()`.

**My Use case:**
I want to listen to the variables and trigger rebuilding of widget tree whenever they change...but not the entire widget tree should be rebuild...only the `ObX()` widgets where something has been changed.

**Currently**
I am using an big ObX() object and put all observables in there...I fear that the whole `ObX()` will be rebuild if an observed variable in it changes...

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(S.current.menuLatestEvents),
      ),
      drawer: const AppDrawer(),
      body: controller.isClientVersionNOTSupported.value
          ? const UpdateAppCard()
          : Container(
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              child: Obx(
                () {
                  return controller.isLoading.value
                      ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                      : controller.isError.value
                          ? ErrorCard(
                              controller: controller,
                              retryFunction: () => controller.getEvents(),
                            )
```

The observable outside of ObX()...do I correctly listen to it?

I can not use `ever()`, because it can not be used in an `if-statement`, because *it´s not static*... So how to only listen to one variable and using it in if-statement without needing of using an widget like `ObX()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the `update()` function offered by the `GetBuilder` widget to rebuild just particular branches of your widget tree while listening for changes in a `Rx` variable. By using this technique, you may rebuild only a portion of your widget tree rather than the full widget tree.

Example:

```
class HomeScreenController extends MyGetXController {
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  var isError = true.obs;
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final HomeScreenController controller = Get.put(HomeScreenController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Listen to the isLoading variable and update the CircularProgressIndicator
            GetBuilder<HomeScreenController>(
              id: 'isLoading',
              builder: (_) {
                if (controller.isLoading.value) {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            ),
            // Listen to the isError variable and update the ErrorCard
            GetBuilder<HomeScreenController>(
              id: 'isError',
              builder: (_) {
                if (controller.isError.value) {
                  return ErrorCard(
                    controller: controller,
                    retryFunction: () => controller.getEvents(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```